# Array.map function returns undefined or [undefined]

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hey guys i am a little bit puzzled here . What am i doing wrong i have and object array in a external file that is looking something like this :

```
import moment from "moment";

export default [{
    filterOn: "startDate",
    startDate: moment("01/01/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY").startOf("day"),
    endDate: moment().startOf("day")
}];
```

Then i have my array imported via `props` like :  `props.datePickerDefinition`

Into a separate file i am fetching the array and i try to extract the value from the array to some states via  `useState` and `setState`

```
const [fromToDatePickerColumn, setFromToDatePickerColumn] = useState();
const [dateFrom, setDateFrom] = useState();
const [dateTo, setDateTo] = useState();
```

My goal is to use the `useEffect` function and update the state of these three elements with a switch case :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    props.datePickerDefinition.map((date) => {
        switch (typeof date) {
            case 'string':
                setFromToDatePickerColumn(date.fromToDatePickerFilterOn)
            break;

            case'moment' :
                setDateFrom(date.startDate)
                setDateTO(date.endDate)

        }
    })
})
```

So i have two questions first . Can i use a `switch` case to check on a moment object ? And the second and most important one is why when i extract the value from the `.map` function i recieve `undefined` , but if i check the value by  `props.datePickerDefinition.map((date) => console.log(date))`  i see it . Can someone give me a hand i will be very gratefull to understand what am i doing wrong .

I have tried with the `.forEach` function :

```js
const array1 = [{first:'a', second:'b', third:'c'}];

const test = array1.forEach(element => element.first);

console.log(test)
```

And also .map :

```js
const array1 = [{first:'a', second:'b', third:'c'}];

const test = array1.map(element => element.first);

console.log(test)
```

But in this case it returns me `["a"]` and i need only the value and not the `Array`

Comment: Would you need to return something from the map? As I see, you don't return anything. If I see a map function and it doesn't return anything, it confuses me. A forEach would be better if you don't want to return anything

Comment: Basically the `fromToDatePickerColumn` has to be setted to `"startDate"` ... from the data from the array and so on and forth , but in my case is returning me `undefined`

Comment: And did you verify that the `typeof date` returns `"moment"`? Does it not return `"object"`?

Comment: Ah yes i have to check on `object` not on `moment` , but never the less if i try to `const test = props.datePickerDefinition.forEach((date) => date.filterOn)` the result is still `undefined` .... i don't get it

Comment: If you know the array has only one element, you could just `const test = array1.map(element => element.first)[0];` or even better `array1[0].first`

Comment: With the forEach example `const test = array1.forEach(element => element.first);`, the test value will be undefined because the forEach doesn't return anything.

Comment: In updated snippet, forEach won't return any value. So you see log as undefined. Where as map takes array as input and returns a new array of same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to again iterate over the date to set the states. But map won't fit here.
Try below code:

```
useEffect(() => { 

 props.datePickerDefinition.forEach(date =>{
   for(let key in date){
     const dateItem = date[key];
     switch (typeof dateItem) {
      case 'string':
          setFromToDatePickerColumn(date.filterOn);
      break;

      case 'object' :
          setDateFrom(date.startDate);
          setDateTo(date.endDate);
          break;
      default: break;

    }
   }
 })
})
```

Comment: Yeah mate this has done the job . So i get it know after the first iteration i have iterate on the date also . Thanks for the help . Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Add return statement inside switch cases in your map